# Remove class when opeing a dialog with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm using jQuery UI for my project and in particular `selectables` and `dialogs`. When I have a selected HTML item and open a dialog, the selected item gets un(de)selected. I searched why it un(de)selects it but with no result. Does anybody know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in your code I discovered some lacks, the main are related to the lines with a comment having my nickname okai, so look inside for this string.

Because I do not understand your language, I'm sorry, I changed the label move in english and I tested for the move function in context menu and now it works.
I moved the move functionality in your menu at first place so you may see directly in the "snippet run" without opening it in full mode.

If you need to add the feature to deselect a table row when clicking outside the table you may do something like:

```
$('html').click(function(e){
....
if ($(e.target).is('html')) {
   ins.element.find('.ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected');
}
```

Let me know.

```js
$(function () {
  $("table tbody.toBeSelected").selectable({
    stop: function() {
      $(".ui-selected", this)
      .each(function() {
        var index = $("table tbody").index(this);
      });

    }
  });
  $('html').click(function(e){
    var ins = $( "table tbody.toBeSelected" ).selectable( "instance" );
    // clear the selected list
    ins.selectees = [];
    // remove the selected class
    /*****
                 *
                 * okai: The following line is your problem: comment it!
                 *
                 */
    //ins.element.find('.ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected');
  });
  var context = $('table tbody.toBeSelected').nuContextMenu({
    hideAfterClick: true,
    items: 'tr.tabledata',
    callback: function(key, element) {

      if(key === "delete"){
        var classElements = document.querySelectorAll("tr.ui-selected td.filename");
        var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
        for(var x = 0;x < classElements.length;x++){
          var result;
          result = classElements[x].innerHTML;
          $.ajax({
            async: true,
            method: 'POST',
            url: '../public/deletefile',
            data: { filename: result, "_token": csrf  },
            success: function(response) {
              $( "tr.ui-selected" ).remove(response);
            }
          });
        };
      }
      if(key === "download") {

      };
      if(key === "info") {
        fileInfo();
        dialogInfo.dialog('open');
      };
      if(key === "share") {
        share();
        dialogShare.dialog('open');
      };
      if(key === 'version') {
        dialogVersion.dialog('open');
        selectedFile();
      }
      if(key === 'move') {
        dialogMoveTo.dialog('option', 'position', {my: 'center', at: "center", of: $(this) }).dialog('open');
      }
    },
    menu: [
      {
        name: 'move',
        title: 'move',
        icon: 'exchange',
        class: 'move'
      },
      {
        name: 'download',
        title: 'Изтегли',
        icon: 'cloud-download',
        class: 'download'
      },
      {
        name: 'void'
      },
      {
        name: 'delete',
        title: 'Изтрий',
        icon: 'trash',
        class: 'delete'
      },
      {
        name: 'info',
        title: 'Инфромация',
        icon: 'info-circle',
        class: 'info'
      },
      {
        name: 'share',
        title: 'Спдели',
        icon: 'share-alt',
        class: 'share'
      },
      {
        name: 'version',
        title: 'Версии',
        icon: 'eye',
        class: 'version'
      }]

  });
  var dialogMoveTo;
  dialogMoveTo = $( "#dialog-moveto" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    width: 200,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Премести',
    close: function() {
      dialogMoveTo.dialog( "close" );
    },
    buttons: {
      "Премести": function() {
        var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
        var classElements = document.querySelectorAll("tr.ui-selected td.filename");
        var result = classElements[0].innerHTML;
        var getSelect = document.getElementById("folders");
        var seletedOption = getSelect.options[getSelect.selectedIndex].text;

        $.ajax({
          async: true,
          method: 'POST',
          url: '../public/getfolder',
          data: {"folder": seletedOption, "filename": result, "_token": csrf},
          complete: function(response) {
            console.log(response);

          }
        });
        dialogMoveTo.dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  });


});


(function($, window, document, undefined) {

  'use strict';

  var plugin = 'nuContextMenu';

  var defaults = {
    hideAfterClick: false,
    contextMenuClass: 'nu-context-menu',
    activeClass: 'active'
  };

  var nuContextMenu = function(container, options) {
    this.container = $(container);
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = plugin;
    this.init();
  };

  $.extend(nuContextMenu.prototype, {
    init: function() {

      if (this.options.items) {
        this.items = $(this.options.items);
      }

      if (this._buildContextMenu()) {
        this._bindEvents();
        this._menuVisible = this._menu.hasClass(this.options.activeClass);
      }
    },

    _getCallback: function() {
      return ((this.options.callback && typeof this.options.callback ===
               'function') ? this.options.callback : function() {});
    },

    _buildContextMenu: function() {

      // Create context menu
      this._menu = $('<div>')
      .addClass(this.options.contextMenuClass)
      .append('<ul>');

      var menuArray = this.options.menu,
          menuList = this._menu.children('ul');

      // Create menu items
      $.each(menuArray, function(index, element) {

        var item;

        if (element !== null && typeof element !=='object') {
          return;
        }

        if (element.name === 'void') {
          item = $('<hr>');
          menuList.append(item);
          return;
        }

        item = $('<li>')
        .attr('data-key', element.name)
        .addClass(element.class)
        .prepend("<a>" + element.title);


        if (element.icon) {
          var icon = $('<i>')
          .addClass('fa fa-' + element.icon.toString());
          item.prepend(icon);
        }

        menuList.append(item);

      });

      $('body')
      .append(this._menu);

      return true;

    },

    _pDefault: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    },

    _contextMenu: function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      // Store the value of this
      // So it can be used in the listItem click event
      var _this = this;
      var element = event.target;

      if (this._menuVisible || this.options.disable) {
        return false;
      }

      var callback = this._getCallback();
      var listItems = this._menu.children('ul')
      .children('li');

      listItems.off()
      .on('click', function() {

        var key = $(this)
        .attr('data-key');
        callback(key, element);
        if (_this.options.hideAfterClick) {
          _this.closeMenu();
        }
      });

      this.openMenu();
      this._menu.css({
        'top': event.pageY + 'px',
        'left': event.pageX + 'px'
      });

      return true;
    },

    _onMouseDown: function(event) {
      // Remove menu if clicked outside
      if (!$(event.target)
          .parents('.' + this.options.contextMenuClass)
          .length) {
        this.closeMenu();
      }
    },

    _bindEvents: function() {

      if (this.items) {
        // Make it possible to bind to dynamically created items
        this.container.on('contextmenu', this.options.items,
                          $.proxy(this._contextMenu,
                                  this));
      } else {
        this.container.on('contextmenu', $.proxy(this._contextMenu,
                                                 this));
      }

      // Remove menu on click
      $(document)
      .on('mousedown', $.proxy(this._onMouseDown, this));

    },

    disable: function() {
      this.options.disable = true;
      return true;
    },

    destroy: function() {
      if (this.items) {
        this.container.off('contextmenu', this.options.items);
      } else {
        this.container.off('contextmenu');
      }
      this._menu.remove();
      return true;
    },

    openMenu: function() {
      this._menu.addClass(this.options.activeClass);
      this._menuVisible = true;
      return true;
    },

    closeMenu: function() {
      this._menu.removeClass(this.options.activeClass);
      this._menuVisible = false;
      return true;
    }

  });




  $.fn[plugin] = function(options) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    return this.each(function() {
      var item = $(this),
          instance = item.data(plugin);
      if (!instance) {
        item.data(plugin, new nuContextMenu(this, options));
      } else {
        if (typeof options === 'string' && options[0] !== '_' &&
            options !== 'init') {
          instance[options].apply(instance, args);
        }
      }
    });
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);
var selectable = $.widget("ui.selectable", $.ui.mouse, {
  version: "1.11.4",
  options: {
    appendTo: "body",
    autoRefresh: true,
    distance: 0,
    filter: "*",
    tolerance: "touch",

    // callbacks
    selected: null,
    selecting: null,
    start: null,
    stop: null,
    unselected: null,
    unselecting: null
  },
  _create: function() {
    var selectees,
        that = this;

    this.element.addClass("ui-selectable");

    this.dragged = false;

    // cache selectee children based on filter
    this.refresh = function() {
      selectees = $(that.options.filter, that.element[0]);
      selectees.addClass("ui-selectee");
      selectees.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            pos = $this.offset();
        $.data(this, "selectable-item", {
          element: this,
          $element: $this,
          left: pos.left,
          top: pos.top,
          right: pos.left + $this.outerWidth(),
          bottom: pos.top + $this.outerHeight(),
          startselected: false,
          selected: $this.hasClass("ui-selected"),
          selecting: $this.hasClass("ui-selecting"),
          unselecting: $this.hasClass("ui-unselecting")
        });
      });
    };
    this.refresh();

    this.selectees = selectees.addClass("ui-selectee");

    this._mouseInit();

    this.helper = $("<div class='ui-selectable-helper'></div>");
  },

  _destroy: function() {
    this.selectees
    .removeClass("ui-selectee")
    .removeData("selectable-item");
    this.element
    .removeClass("ui-selectable ui-selectable-disabled");
    this._mouseDestroy();
  },

  _mouseStart: function(event) {
    var that = this,
        options = this.options;

    this.opos = [ event.pageX, event.pageY ];

    if (this.options.disabled) {
      return;
    }

    this.selectees = $(options.filter, this.element[0]);

    this._trigger("start", event);

    $(options.appendTo).append(this.helper);
    // position helper (lasso)
    this.helper.css({
      "left": event.pageX,
      "top": event.pageY,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0
    });

    if (options.autoRefresh) {
      this.refresh();
    }

    this.selectees.filter(".ui-selected").each(function() {
      var selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item");
      selectee.startselected = true;
      if (!event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey) {
        selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-selected");
        selectee.selected = false;
        selectee.$element.addClass("ui-unselecting");
        selectee.unselecting = true;
        // selectable UNSELECTING callback
        that._trigger("unselecting", event, {
          unselecting: selectee.element
        });
      }
    });

    $(event.target).parents().addBack().each(function() {
      var doSelect,
          selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item");
      if (selectee) {
        doSelect = (!event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey) || !selectee.$element.hasClass("ui-selected");
        selectee.$element

        .addClass(doSelect ? "ui-selecting" : "ui-unselecting");
        selectee.unselecting = !doSelect;
        selectee.selecting = doSelect;
        selectee.selected = doSelect;
        // selectable (UN)SELECTING callback
        if (doSelect) {
          that._trigger("selecting", event, {
            selecting: selectee.element
          });
        } else {
          that._trigger("unselecting", event, {
            unselecting: selectee.element
          });
        }
        return false;
      }
    });

  },

  _mouseDrag: function(event) {

    this.dragged = true;

    if (this.options.disabled) {
      return;
    }

    var tmp,
        that = this,
        options = this.options,
        x1 = this.opos[0],
        y1 = this.opos[1],
        x2 = event.pageX,
        y2 = event.pageY;

    if (x1 > x2) { tmp = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = tmp; }
    if (y1 > y2) { tmp = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = tmp; }
    this.helper.css({ left: x1, top: y1, width: x2 - x1, height: y2 - y1 });

    this.selectees.each(function() {
      var selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item"),
          hit = false;

      //prevent helper from being selected if appendTo: selectable
      if (!selectee || selectee.element === that.element[0]) {
        return;
      }

      if (options.tolerance === "touch") {
        hit = ( !(selectee.left > x2 || selectee.right < x1 || selectee.top > y2 || selectee.bottom < y1) );
      } else if (options.tolerance === "fit") {
        hit = (selectee.left > x1 && selectee.right < x2 && selectee.top > y1 && selectee.bottom < y2);
      }

      if (hit) {
        // SELECT
        if (selectee.selected) {

          selectee.selected = false;
        }
        if (selectee.unselecting) {
          selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-unselecting");
          selectee.unselecting = false;
        }
        if (!selectee.selecting) {
          selectee.$element.addClass("ui-selecting");
          selectee.selecting = true;
          // selectable SELECTING callback
          that._trigger("selecting", event, {
            selecting: selectee.element
          });
        }
      } else {
        // UNSELECT
        if (selectee.selecting) {
          if ((event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) && selectee.startselected) {
            selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-selecting");
            selectee.selecting = false;
            selectee.$element.addClass("ui-selected");
            selectee.selected = true;
          } else {
            selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-selecting");
            selectee.selecting = false;
            if (selectee.startselected) {
              selectee.$element.addClass("ui-unselecting");
              selectee.unselecting = true;
            }
            // selectable UNSELECTING callback
            that._trigger("unselecting", event, {
              unselecting: selectee.element
            });
          }
        }
        if (selectee.selected) {
          if (!event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey && !selectee.startselected) {

            selectee.selected = false;

            selectee.$element.addClass("ui-unselecting");
            selectee.unselecting = true;
            // selectable UNSELECTING callback
            that._trigger("unselecting", event, {
              unselecting: selectee.element
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });

    return false;
  },

  _mouseStop: function(event) {
    var that = this;

    this.dragged = false;

    $(".ui-unselecting", this.element[0]).each(function() {
      var selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item");
      selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-unselecting");
      selectee.unselecting = false;
      selectee.startselected = false;
      that._trigger("unselected", event, {
        unselected: selectee.element
      });
    });
    $(".ui-selecting", this.element[0]).each(function() {
      var selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item");
      selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-selecting").addClass("ui-selected");
      selectee.selecting = false;
      selectee.selected = true;
      selectee.startselected = true;
      that._trigger("selected", event, {
        selected: selectee.element
      });
    });
    this._trigger("stop", event);

    this.helper.remove();

    return false;
  }

});
```

```css
#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#selectable li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}

.nu-context-menu {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 9999;

}

.nu-context-menu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.nu-context-menu ul {
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.nu-context-menu ul li a, .nu-context-menu ul li {
  clear: both;
  color: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 108px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nu-context-menu ul li:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #333;
}

.nu-context-menu ul hr {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: 0;
  color: #e8e8e8;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}
/*
*
* okai: Add the following line to make table row selectable
*
*/
.ui-selectable>.ui-selected {
  background-color: #a6c9e2;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="content block">
    <div id="results">
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Number:</th>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <th>Size:</th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class="toBeSelected">
            <tr class="tabledata">
                <td>2</td>
                <td class="filename">100KILA - 100 gaidi.mp3</td>
                <td>7.93 MB</td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="tabledata">
                <td>1</td>
                <td class="filename">3.pdf</td>
                <td>385.52 KB</td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="dialog-moveto">
    <div class="moveto">
        <select name="folders" id="folders">

            <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
            <option>{{ $folder->folder }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, this may solve my problem. Actually when I select an item and then from a context menu open a dialog window the selected item becomes undelected. In ui-jquery removed every row which contains `.removeClass("ui-selected")` but with no result

Comment: Unfortunately, something removes the `ui-selected` class. Didn''t worked

Comment: Look at my answer below

Comment: @Alex Snippet Updated, let me know

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table tbody.toBeSelected").selectable({
      
        stop: function() {
            $(".ui-selected", this)
                .each(function() {
                    var index = $("table tbody").index(this);   
                });    

        }
    });
  $('html').click(function(){
    var ins = $( "table tbody.toBeSelected" ).selectable( "instance" );
    // clear the selected list
    ins.selectees = [];
    // remove the selected class
    ins.element.find('.ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected');
  });
  var context = $('table tbody.toBeSelected').nuContextMenu({
        hideAfterClick: true,        
        items: 'tr.tabledata',
        callback: function(key, element) {
            
            if(key === "delete"){
                var classElements = document.querySelectorAll("tr.ui-selected td.filename");
                var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
                for(var x = 0;x < classElements.length;x++){
                    var result;
                    result = classElements[x].innerHTML;
                    $.ajax({
                        async: true,                      
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '../public/deletefile',
                        data: { filename: result, "_token": csrf  },
                        success: function(response) {
                           $( "tr.ui-selected" ).remove(response);              
                        }
                    });
                };
            }
            if(key === "download") {
                
            };
            if(key === "info") {
                fileInfo();
                dialogInfo.dialog('open');
            };
            if(key === "share") {
               share();
               dialogShare.dialog('open');
            };
            if(key === 'version') {
                dialogVersion.dialog('open');
                selectedFile();
            }
            if(key === 'move') {
                
                dialogMoveTo.dialog('option', 'position', {my: 'center', at: "center", of: $(this) }).dialog('open');
            }
        },
        menu: [
        {
            name: 'download',
            title: 'Изтегли',
            icon: 'cloud-download',
            class: 'download'
        }, 
        {
            name: 'void'
        },    
        {
            name: 'delete',
            title: 'Изтрий',
            icon: 'trash',
            class: 'delete'
        },
        {
            name: 'info',
            title: 'Инфромация',
            icon: 'info-circle',
            class: 'info'
        },
        {
            name: 'share',
            title: 'Спдели',
            icon: 'share-alt',
            class: 'share'
        },
        {
            name: 'version',
            title: 'Версии',
            icon: 'eye',
            class: 'version'
        },
        {
            name: 'move',
            title: 'Премести',
            icon: 'exchange',
            class: 'move'
        }]

    });
  var dialogMoveTo;
    dialogMoveTo = $( "#dialog-moveto" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: 200,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Премести',
        close: function() {
            dialogMoveTo.dialog( "close" );
        },
        buttons: {
            "Премести": function() {
                var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
                var classElements = document.querySelectorAll("tr.ui-selected td.filename");
                var result = classElements[0].innerHTML;
                var getSelect = document.getElementById("folders");
                var seletedOption = getSelect.options[getSelect.selectedIndex].text;
                
                    $.ajax({
                        async: true,                      
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '../public/getfolder',
                        data: {"folder": seletedOption, "filename": result, "_token": csrf},
                        complete: function(response) {
                            console.log(response);     
                            
                        }
                    });    
                dialogMoveTo.dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
  
  
});  


(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  
  'use strict';
  
  var plugin = 'nuContextMenu';
  
  var defaults = {
    hideAfterClick: false,
    contextMenuClass: 'nu-context-menu',
    activeClass: 'active'
  };
  
  var nuContextMenu = function(container, options) {
    this.container = $(container);
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = plugin;
    this.init();
  };
  
  $.extend(nuContextMenu.prototype, {
    init: function() {
      
      if (this.options.items) {
        this.items = $(this.options.items);
      }
      
      if (this._buildContextMenu()) {
        this._bindEvents();
        this._menuVisible = this._menu.hasClass(this.options.activeClass);
      }
    },
    
    _getCallback: function() {
      return ((this.options.callback && typeof this.options.callback ===
      'function') ? this.options.callback : function() {});
    },
    
    _buildContextMenu: function() {
      
      // Create context menu
      this._menu = $('<div>')
      .addClass(this.options.contextMenuClass)
      .append('<ul>');
      
      var menuArray = this.options.menu,
      menuList = this._menu.children('ul');
      
      // Create menu items
      $.each(menuArray, function(index, element) {
        
        var item;
        
        if (element !== null && typeof element !=='object') {
          return;
          }
          
          if (element.name === 'void') {
            item = $('<hr>');
            menuList.append(item);
            return;
          }
          
          item = $('<li>')
          .attr('data-key', element.name)
          .addClass(element.class)
          .prepend("<a>" + element.title);
          
          
          if (element.icon) {
            var icon = $('<i>')
            .addClass('fa fa-' + element.icon.toString());
            item.prepend(icon);
          }
          
          menuList.append(item);
          
      });
      
      $('body')
      .append(this._menu);
      
      return true;
      
    },
    
    _pDefault: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    },
    
    _contextMenu: function(event) {
      
      event.preventDefault();
      
      // Store the value of this
      // So it can be used in the listItem click event
      var _this = this;
      var element = event.target;
      
      if (this._menuVisible || this.options.disable) {
        return false;
      }
      
      var callback = this._getCallback();
      var listItems = this._menu.children('ul')
      .children('li');
      
      listItems.off()
      .on('click', function() {
        
        var key = $(this)
        .attr('data-key');
        callback(key, element);
        if (_this.options.hideAfterClick) {
          _this.closeMenu();
        }
      });
      
      this.openMenu();
      this._menu.css({
        'top': event.pageY + 'px',
        'left': event.pageX + 'px'
      });
      
      return true;
    },
    
    _onMouseDown: function(event) {
      // Remove menu if clicked outside
      if (!$(event.target)
        .parents('.' + this.options.contextMenuClass)
        .length) {
        this.closeMenu();
        }
    },
    
    _bindEvents: function() {
      
      if (this.items) {
        // Make it possible to bind to dynamically created items
        this.container.on('contextmenu', this.options.items,
                          $.proxy(this._contextMenu,
                                  this));
      } else {
        this.container.on('contextmenu', $.proxy(this._contextMenu,
                                                 this));
      }
      
      // Remove menu on click
      $(document)
      .on('mousedown', $.proxy(this._onMouseDown, this));
      
    },
    
    disable: function() {
      this.options.disable = true;
      return true;
    },
    
    destroy: function() {
      if (this.items) {
        this.container.off('contextmenu', this.options.items);
      } else {
        this.container.off('contextmenu');
      }
      this._menu.remove();
      return true;
    },
    
    openMenu: function() {
      this._menu.addClass(this.options.activeClass);
      this._menuVisible = true;
      return true;
    },
    
    closeMenu: function() {
      this._menu.removeClass(this.options.activeClass);
      this._menuVisible = false;
      return true;
    }
    
  });
   
    
   
  
  $.fn[plugin] = function(options) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    
    return this.each(function() {
      var item = $(this),
                     instance = item.data(plugin);
                     if (!instance) {
                       item.data(plugin, new nuContextMenu(this, options));
                     } else {
                       if (typeof options === 'string' && options[0] !== '_' &&
                         options !== 'init') {
                         instance[options].apply(instance, args);
                         }
                     }
    });
  };
  
})(jQuery, window, document);
var selectable = $.widget("ui.selectable", $.ui.mouse, {
version: "1.11.4",
options: {
 appendTo: "body",
 autoRefresh: true,
 distance: 0,
 filter: "*",
 tolerance: "touch",

 // callbacks
 selected: null,
 selecting: null,
 start: null,
 stop: null,
 unselected: null,
 unselecting: null
},
_create: function() {
 var selectees,
  that = this;

 this.element.addClass("ui-selectable");

 this.dragged = false;

 // cache selectee children based on filter
 this.refresh = function() {
  selectees = $(that.options.filter, that.element[0]);
  selectees.addClass("ui-selectee");
  selectees.each(function() {
   var $this = $(this),
    pos = $this.offset();
   $.data(this, "selectable-item", {
    element: this,
    $element: $this,
    left: pos.left,
    top: pos.top,
    right: pos.left + $this.outerWidth(),
    bottom: pos.top + $this.outerHeight(),
    startselected: false,
    selected: $this.hasClass("ui-selected"),
    selecting: $this.hasClass("ui-selecting"),
    unselecting: $this.hasClass("ui-unselecting")
   });
  });
 };
 this.refresh();

 this.selectees = selectees.addClass("ui-selectee");

 this._mouseInit();

 this.helper = $("<div class='ui-selectable-helper'></div>");
},

_destroy: function() {
 this.selectees
  .removeClass("ui-selectee")
  .removeData("selectable-item");
 this.element
  .removeClass("ui-selectable ui-selectable-disabled");
 this._mouseDestroy();
},

_mouseStart: function(event) {
 var that = this,
  options = this.options;

 this.opos = [ event.pageX, event.pageY ];

 if (this.options.disabled) {
  return;
 }

 this.selectees = $(options.filter, this.element[0]);

 this._trigger("start", event);

 $(options.appendTo).append(this.helper);
 // position helper (lasso)
 this.helper.css({
  "left": event.pageX,
  "top": event.pageY,
  "width": 0,
  "height": 0
 });

 if (options.autoRefresh) {
  this.refresh();
 }

 this.selectees.filter(".ui-selected").each(function() {
  var selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item");
  selectee.startselected = true;
  if (!event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey) {
   selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-selected");
   selectee.selected = false;
   selectee.$element.addClass("ui-unselecting");
   selectee.unselecting = true;
   // selectable UNSELECTING callback
   that._trigger("unselecting", event, {
    unselecting: selectee.element
   });
  }
 });

 $(event.target).parents().addBack().each(function() {
  var doSelect,
   selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item");
  if (selectee) {
   doSelect = (!event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey) || !selectee.$element.hasClass("ui-selected");
   selectee.$element
    
    .addClass(doSelect ? "ui-selecting" : "ui-unselecting");
   selectee.unselecting = !doSelect;
   selectee.selecting = doSelect;
   selectee.selected = doSelect;
   // selectable (UN)SELECTING callback
   if (doSelect) {
    that._trigger("selecting", event, {
     selecting: selectee.element
    });
   } else {
    that._trigger("unselecting", event, {
     unselecting: selectee.element
    });
   }
   return false;
  }
 });

},

_mouseDrag: function(event) {

 this.dragged = true;

 if (this.options.disabled) {
  return;
 }

 var tmp,
  that = this,
  options = this.options,
  x1 = this.opos[0],
  y1 = this.opos[1],
  x2 = event.pageX,
  y2 = event.pageY;

 if (x1 > x2) { tmp = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = tmp; }
 if (y1 > y2) { tmp = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = tmp; }
 this.helper.css({ left: x1, top: y1, width: x2 - x1, height: y2 - y1 });

 this.selectees.each(function() {
  var selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item"),
   hit = false;

  //prevent helper from being selected if appendTo: selectable
  if (!selectee || selectee.element === that.element[0]) {
   return;
  }

  if (options.tolerance === "touch") {
   hit = ( !(selectee.left > x2 || selectee.right < x1 || selectee.top > y2 || selectee.bottom < y1) );
  } else if (options.tolerance === "fit") {
   hit = (selectee.left > x1 && selectee.right < x2 && selectee.top > y1 && selectee.bottom < y2);
  }

  if (hit) {
   // SELECT
   if (selectee.selected) {
    
    selectee.selected = false;
   }
   if (selectee.unselecting) {
    selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-unselecting");
    selectee.unselecting = false;
   }
   if (!selectee.selecting) {
    selectee.$element.addClass("ui-selecting");
    selectee.selecting = true;
    // selectable SELECTING callback
    that._trigger("selecting", event, {
     selecting: selectee.element
    });
   }
  } else {
   // UNSELECT
   if (selectee.selecting) {
    if ((event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) && selectee.startselected) {
     selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-selecting");
     selectee.selecting = false;
     selectee.$element.addClass("ui-selected");
     selectee.selected = true;
    } else {
     selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-selecting");
     selectee.selecting = false;
     if (selectee.startselected) {
      selectee.$element.addClass("ui-unselecting");
      selectee.unselecting = true;
     }
     // selectable UNSELECTING callback
     that._trigger("unselecting", event, {
      unselecting: selectee.element
     });
    }
   }
   if (selectee.selected) {
    if (!event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey && !selectee.startselected) {
     
     selectee.selected = false;

     selectee.$element.addClass("ui-unselecting");
     selectee.unselecting = true;
     // selectable UNSELECTING callback
     that._trigger("unselecting", event, {
      unselecting: selectee.element
     });
    }
   }
  }
 });

 return false;
},

_mouseStop: function(event) {
 var that = this;

 this.dragged = false;

 $(".ui-unselecting", this.element[0]).each(function() {
  var selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item");
  selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-unselecting");
  selectee.unselecting = false;
  selectee.startselected = false;
  that._trigger("unselected", event, {
   unselected: selectee.element
  });
 });
 $(".ui-selecting", this.element[0]).each(function() {
  var selectee = $.data(this, "selectable-item");
  selectee.$element.removeClass("ui-selecting").addClass("ui-selected");
  selectee.selecting = false;
  selectee.selected = true;
  selectee.startselected = true;
  that._trigger("selected", event, {
   selected: selectee.element
  });
 });
 this._trigger("stop", event);

 this.helper.remove();

 return false;
}

});
```

```css
.nu-context-menu {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
  
}

.nu-context-menu.active {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.nu-context-menu ul {
    font-size: 15px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    padding: 4px 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.nu-context-menu ul li a, .nu-context-menu ul li {
    clear: both;
    color: #777;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 108px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nu-context-menu ul li:hover {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    color: #333;
}

.nu-context-menu ul hr {
    background: #e8e8e8;
    border: 0;
    color: #e8e8e8;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<head>

<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="content block">
                <div id="results">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Number:</th>
                                <th>Name:</th>
                                <th>Size:</th>                             
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tbody class="toBeSelected">
                                                        <tr class="tabledata">
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td class="filename">100KILA - 100 gaidi.mp3</td>
                                <td>7.93 MB</td>
                                
                            </tr>  
                            <tr class="tabledata">
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td class="filename">3.pdf</td>
                                <td>385.52 KB</td>
                                
                            </tr>  
                        </tbody>
                    </table>      
                </div>     
            </div>

<div id="dialog-moveto">
            <div class="moveto">
                <select name="folders" id="folders">
                    
                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> 
                            <option>{{ $folder->folder }}</option>         
                </select>
            </div>
</div>
    </body>
```

Here is a part of my project byut I don't get it why I can't make the HTML selectable